# System.MissingMethodException: Method not found Windows Store App Deployed on Surface RT

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, sideloading

I am developing a simple Tongue Twister Windows Store App using C#.  The App works fine on my development environment (Windows 8.1 Pro, x64, Visual Studio 2013) and it **only crashes** when run on a Surface RT (Windows RT 8.1 Preview).  When I sideload the package to the Surface, I deploy it for ARM; whereas, locally I run with x86.

The App uses the (Surface) microphone to gather the user's voice and when the button 'Start Listening' is pressed it crashes producing the following error:

> ```
> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Dispose()"
> ```

I have debugged this issue remotely connecting my developer machine to the Surface but I can't make it crash.  Yet the piece code that is executed when the 'Start Listening'  button is pressed is:

```
SpeechRecognitionResult speechResult = await mRecognizer.RecognizeSpeechToTextAsync();

/** Prior code **/


private ICommand mListen;
...
mListen = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnListen);

public ICommand Listen
{
 get
        {
         return mListen;
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any of the BCL async NuGet packages installed? Remove them.

Comment: @SLaks hey, no I do not use NuGet packages.

Comment: That method was probably added after the preview.

Comment: @SLaks so your recommendation is to update the Surface to 8.1 and then give it a try? Thanks